# delaysContentTouches only on specific elements without subclassing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, subclassing

I have a simple question.  In my app, I have a some buttons for navigation inside a `UIScrollView`, which scroll with the content.  This way, when the user enters a text field and the keyboard pops up, the buttons will scroll away for extra space.  However, the buttons don't highlight immediately when I tap on them.  I've learned that I can eliminate this problem by setting `delaysContentTouches` to `NO`, but this makes scrolling nearly impossible, because all the `UITextFields` and buttons in the view also highlight immediately, stealing the scroll.

I have found a way to only not delay the buttons via a `UIScrollView` subclass, so this is an option, but I was wondering if there is another way.  I generally hate subclassing when it is to fix just one little thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` method of UIScrollView is intended to be overridden by subclasses if `delaysContentTouches` is set to YES. So this is the case when subclassing is completely OK.

Comment: I know its "ok," but I kind of hate to subclass anyway.  I'll probably end up using that method anyway, but I asked this question to see if their was another solution.

Comment: For better or for worse, this is the way to do it. Learn to love to subclass, and in the meantime file a bug requesting the ability to do this in the delegate. You could design your subclass to call the delegate!